# how to add object to property on inline declaration

Tags: c#, .net

I'm aware that my question title is not good at all, so please change if someone finds suitable one.

if I had Book and Tag object. One book has many tags. Tag has book. If I creating book object like this

```
Book apressMVC4 = new Book()
{
  Id = 1,
  Name = "Apress Pro asp.net mvc4",
  tags = new List<Tag>{
     new Tag{Id = 1, Name = "mvc", Book = ??? how to add this current book apressMVC4},
}};
```

Obviously I cannot use apressMVC4 variable to store inside Book property of Tag object, so how to do it on this example, on creating book object.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: cross my mind on typing code.

Comment: Usually, this kind of circular references are not good idea. However, you can create instance of a book, then tag objects and after that add it to `tags` property,

Comment: I suggest you overlook the whole design instead. If you absolutely need to implement circular references then I think something is flawed in your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is to break up the statement in two steps:

```
Book apressMVC4 = new Book();

apressMVC4.Id = 1;
apressMVC4.Name = "Apress Pro asp.net mvc4";
apressMVC4.tags = new List<Tag>
{
    new Tag { Id = 1, Name = "mvc", Book = apressMVC4 }
};
```

Obviously, this is no longer a single expression, which may be anoying if you are trying to initialize a field, or using it in a linq expression. But you can always encapsulate this logic in a Book constructor with some parameters:

```
public Book(int id, string name, params Tag[] tags)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.tags = tags
        .Select(tag => new Tag { Id = tag.id, Name = tag.Name, Book = this })
        .ToList();
}
```